# Got trouble with div after floted 2 column

Tags: css

As my question, I floated to div to make a simple 2 column layout but having trouble when I try to add next normal html element. It goes inside the floated divs. I am confused and unable to find appropriate keyword to search this issue. So it may be a duplicated question.

Have a look @ [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LExpYx)

HTML

```
 <div class="container"><div class="hinfo"><div class="hleft">Back</div>
  <div class="hright"><h1>Drive Nuts</h1></div>
  </div>
 <div class="info"><div class="left">Call No.</div>
  <div class="right">Datas</div>
  </div>
  <div class="info"><div class="left">Call No.</div>
  <div class="right">Datas</div>
  </div><div class="info"><div class="left end">Call No.</div>
  <div class="right end">Datas</div>
  </div>
  </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="download"><a href="">Pull now</a></div>
```

Css:

```
    body {
    background: #34495e;
    padding: 50px 0px;
  }

.end {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  }

.container {
    background: #ecf0f1;
    min-height: 480px;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }

.container h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

.right, .left {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    Font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.left {
    width: 20%;
    background: #2c3e50;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #34495e;
  }

.right {
    width: 80%;
    background: #16a085;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1abc9c;
  }

.hright, .hleft {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

.hleft {
    width: 20%;
    background: #c0392b;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e74c3c;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }

.hright {
    width: 80%;
    background: #27ae60;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2ecc71;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 100px
  }

.download {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Here,  `<div class="download"><a href="">Pull now</a></div>` is not showing (It may be shaded by above divs.)

Comment: Please learn how to format code properly for readability.

Comment: Is that what you are trying to achieve? -http://prntscr.com/5pmy1m

Comment: :D I am rockie. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: It is “showing” – you might just have overlooked it because the text of the link has little contrast to the background color … Btw., no need to use an empty div element to do the clearing, you can remove that and let the download div itself do the clearing.

Comment: @MostafaMohsen Yes! absolutely.

Comment: @CBroe I added that empty div later after the trouble started (for test). But can u tell me which css element to use in .download to do it?

Comment: You just set the `clear` on the element itself, what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgroMK

Here you go..

You was trying to add the content after the div of the container therefore it was out of the whole div section you were trying to achieve, commenting out will help you next time.

```
<div class="container"><div class="hinfo"><div class="hleft">Back</div>
  <div class="hright"><h1>Drive Nuts</h1></div>
  </div>
 <div class="info"><div class="left">Call No.</div>
  <div class="right">Datas</div>
  </div>
  <div class="info"><div class="left">Call No.</div>
  <div class="right">Datas</div>
  </div><div class="info"><div class="left end">Call No.</div>
  <div class="right end">Datas</div>
  </div>
  <div class="download"><a href="">Pull now</a></div>
  </div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Just comment your divs...

ex: </div><!--end of container-->

also please mark as an answer if it is.

Comment: @SahriarSaikat also I would really suggest using <table>  for what  you are trying to achieve.

Comment: tables are messy, code junk... nasty. I don't like table. It takes more work to make a table responsive too.